# Border in my site

Tags: html, css, border

straight to the point; there is a margin border in  my site and I can't seem to remove it... I'v tried everything, disabling some of the css,.. I really don't know what that border is doing there.

image:

[image]

the index code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>XylCro Home</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-scrolltofixed-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            // grab the initial top offset of the navigation 
            var stickyNavTop = $('.nav ul').offset().top;

            // our function that decides weather the navigation bar should have "fixed" css position or not.
            var stickyNav = function(){
                var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(); // our current vertical position from the top

                // if we've scrolled more than the navigation, change its position to fixed to stick to top,
                // otherwise change it back to relative
                if (scrollTop > stickyNavTop) { 
                    $('.nav ul').addClass('sticky');
                } else {
                    $('.nav ul').removeClass('sticky'); 
                }
            };

            stickyNav();
            // and run it again every time you scroll
            $(window).scroll(function() {
                stickyNav();
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">
            <!-- div socialbar and logo -->
        </div>
        <div class="nav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Test1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Test2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Test3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Test4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Test5</a></li>
                </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- other divs -->
        <div id="content">
            <!-- content here -->
            <p>Content comes here</p>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            <!-- copyright here --> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

css code:

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
hr{
    display:block;
}
html{
    background-image:url(img/static/bg.jpg);
    background-repeat:repeat;
    background-position:top center;
}
body{
    font-family:helvetica;
    font-size:1em;
    line-height:1.4;
}
#wrapper{
    background-color:#C00;
    background-image:url(img/static/headertest.fw.png);
    background-position:top center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    padding:0;
}
#header{
    height:260; /* need to change */
}
/* social and logo */
.sticky {
    position:fixed;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    border-top: 0;
}
/* content and other divs */
.nav ul{
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #444;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.nav li{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -4px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    line-height: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #888;
}
.nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    transition: .3s background-color;
}
.nav a:hover {
    background-color: #005f5f;
}

.nav a:active {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #444;
    cursor: default;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .nav li {
    width: 120px;
    border-bottom: none;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-size: 1.4em;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`body` tag has default margin. To prevent it, add

```
body {
    margin: 0
}
```

See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7pcdf1v3/) with your code with fix.

Comment: Welcome. To solve problems like this use code inspectors, e.g. Chromes debugger or Firebug for Firefox. It is possible to select any element and see all its parameters: height, width, margin and other. Then problem becomes clear.